# Jquery mobile using keyboard page getting shrink - iOS device only

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Hoping your all doing great!

Am developing hybrid application using Jquery mobile and BackboneJS. Some of page having textfield while am focusing textfield the native keypad open also am able to enter the value. If we click outside of the keypad the keypad hides and total page getting shrink out.

Anybody having solution to fix this issue ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `shrink out`. After the on-screen keyboard is hidden, the page doesn't resize and fill the screen again?

Comment: Yes your right. Its not able to fill perfect UI screen again. This issue happen only on iOS 7 and above version.